# Create a set of buttons to change background color of next cell

Tags: filtering, button, format

I came across the following snippet (sorry can't find original location to give credit).  I would like pressing any of the generated buttons to automatically go to the next cell and color it the respective color.  Thanks in advance.

```
Row[Button[Graphics[{#, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 20], 
CurrentValue[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], Background] = #, 
Appearance -> None] & /@ {Green, Yellow, Pink, Gray}]
```

RIght now I have to manually select the cell and then hit the button.

Comment: Replace `NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]]` with `NextCell[]`, unless you want to move on with each click. Which is the case? That is, you want to switch the bg of the same cell each time or to go through the notebook?

Comment: Perfect - same cell each time.  Thanks much.  Move to answer so I can +1 it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of V10 one can use `NextCell/PreviousCell` to traverse cell neighbours. So the answer is to use:

```
... CurrentValue[NextCell[], Background] = # ...
```

Comment: Kuba - now that this is working, I thought of a better implementation.  If I cut and paste the generated color blocks to the end of a text cell they will still change the color of the next cell; but I was wondering if there is an adjustment I can make that will have it change the current cell the buttons are in.  I could not find CurrentCell command.